# Regex to match any number after certain strings

Tags: regex

I want to match the userid number in a url string that's usually after a `id=` or `/user/`

Examples:

```
http://dummy.url/url/path/id=7623
http://dummy.url/url/path/user/8743
http://dummy.url/url/path/user/56
http://dummy.url/url/path=88772/user/890&more=87273&variables&here=76233
http://dummy.url/url/path/id=2818372
```

I need to match 7623, 8743, 56, 890, 2818372

I haven't tried much on this as I'm a complete noob at regex and I only know how to mach numbers, all numbers, so if the url has any it will match them as well

The numbers will always be positive integers

Comment: If the number will always be at the end,  look up how to extract the last piece of a sting using regex.  And you already know how to match numbers. It shouldn't be too hard to figure out!

Comment: no, the number will not be always at the end

Comment: Your 4th example contradicts that.

Comment: You said usually after id= or /user/ do you know all of the possible strings that will precede the number you want to capture?

Comment: @csirmazbendeguz just edited the 4th example just now so I don't know if you're referring to my edit or to the original question

Comment: @chatton Yes, **id=** and **/user/** are all the possible strings that will precede the number I want to capture

Comment: @StephanieSafflower I was referring to the original :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by defining an alternation:

```
(?:user\/|id=)\K\d+
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kecmbr/1)

Explanation:

```
(?:         # Start of a non-capturing group
    user\/      # Match `user/`
    |           # Or
    id=         # `id=`
)           # End of non-capturing group
\K\d+       # Forget matched strings then match digits
```

Javascript way:

```js
var url = "http://dummy.url/url/path/user/56";
console.log(url.replace(/(user\/|id=)\d+/, function(match, p1) {
 return p1 + 'id';
}));
```

Comment: `var finalUrl = url.replace((?:user\/|id=)\K\d+, id);` Any clues on what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If it is javascript, `\K` is not supported. You have to remove `\K` and instead turn non-capturing group into capturing group `(user\/|id=)\d+` and work on it. Please check update.